# Sub-menu appear on click for that menu item only

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've been looking at this for a while and I'm not sure how to target this.

When I have a menu where the top level menu items have dropdowns, I can write the CSS/JS so that when the button clicks, it shows the dropdown. But when you click one of the buttons, it opens up ALL the dropdowns.

How do I specifically target so that when you click a menu button, it only opens up the sub-menu for that specific button.

```
<li id="Menu-item-2135" class="menu-item">Menu 1
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul></li>

//The JS
$('#menu-item-2135').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active');
  });

//The CSS
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
  &.active {
   display:flex;
  }
}
```

I have been using the menu item ID to target the menu items and using toggleClass('active') for making the sub-menu appear/hide but this means that anytime I add a new menu item to the site that then has a sub-menu, I had to write the JS for that menu ID. Just wondering if there is a way to tweak this so it does all this without needing to specially write it for every menu ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `.find()` to find submenu on clicked element, then , if you need, close all opened submenus before with line  `$('.menu-item').each((i,e)=>{$(e).find('.sub-menu').removeClass('active')})` if you don't neeed that - just remove

```js
$('.menu-item').each((index,element)=>{
  $(element).on('click', ()=>{
    $('.menu-item').each((i,e)=>{$(e).find('.sub-menu').removeClass('active')}) // if you need to close other sub-menu
    $(element).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
  
}
.sub-menu.active {
   display:flex;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item">Menu 1
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">Menu 2
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. How would I tweak this so that if they click on the menu item, it closes the sub-menu?